# How to print correlated features using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get some information on the correlation of the independent variables.

My dataset has a lot of variables, therefore the heatmap is not solution, it is very unreadable.

Currently, I have made a function that returns only those variables that are highly correlated. I would like to change it in way to indicate pairs of correlated features.

The rest of the explanations below:

```
def find_correlated_features(df, threshold, target_variable):

    df_1 = df.drop(target_variable)

    #corr_matrix has in index and columns names of variables
    corr_matrix = df_1.corr().abs()

    # I'm taking only half of this matrix to prevent doubling results
    half_of_matrix = corr_matrix.where(np.triu(np.ones(corr_matrix.shape), k = 1).astype(np.bool))

    # This prints list of columns which are correlated 
    to_drop = [column for column in half_of_matrix.columns if any(half_of_matrix[column] > threshold)]
    
    return to_drop
```

The best if this function would return pandas dataframe with column_1; column_2; corr_coef only variables that are above threshold.

Something like this:

```
output = {'feature name 1': column_name,
          'feature name 2': index,
          'correlation coef': corr_coef}

output_list.append(output)
return pd.DataFrame(output_list).sort_values('corr_coef', ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**After Edit:**

After OP comment and @user6386471 answer, I've read again the question and I think that a simply restructure of the correlation matrix would work, with no need of loops. Like `half_of_matrix.stack().reset_index()` plus filters. See:

```
def find_correlated_features(df, threshold, target_variable):
    # remove target column
    df = df.drop(columns=target_variable).copy()
    # Get correlation matrix
    corr_matrix = df.corr().abs()
    # Take half of the matrix to prevent doubling results
    corr_matrix = corr_matrix.where(np.triu(np.ones(corr_matrix.shape), k = 1).astype(np.bool))
    # Restructure correlation matrix to dataframe
    df = corr_matrix.stack().reset_index()
    df.columns = ['feature1', 'feature2', 'corr_coef']
    # Apply filter and sort coefficients
    df = df[df.corr_coef >= threshold].sort_values('corr_coef', ascending=False)
    return df
```

---

**Original answer:**

You can easily create a `Series` with the coefficients above a threshold like this:

```py
s = df.corr().loc[target_col]
s[s.abs() >= threshold]
```

where `df` is your dataframe, `target_col` your target column, and `threshold`, you know, the threshold.

---

**Example:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

print(df.shape)
# -> (150, 5)

print(df.head())

   sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width species
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa
```

```py
def find_correlated_features(df, threshold, target_variable):
    s = df.corr().loc[target_variable].drop(target_variable)
    return s[s.abs() >= threshold]

find_correlated_features(df, .7, 'sepal_length')
```

output:

```
petal_length    0.871754
petal_width     0.817941
Name: sepal_length, dtype: float64
```

You can use `.to_frame()` followed by `.T` to the outptut to get a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Thank you very much for help but this solution does not work for me because I need a tool to check the correlation between independent variables. Therefore, I remove the target variable from the very beginning in my function. However, I will also need such a tool so great, thank you again! Cheers!

Comment: Got it! So @user6386471 solution should work for you. I've updated the answer to a similar solution without using loop. It's basically your code, changing just the end to restructure the matrix to a dataframe where we can filter out the coefficients below the threshold, and sort them.

Comment: Yes, this solution works for me. The results look a little suspicious but I think this is related to the nature of the data. I'm sure I'm closer to the solution thanks to you. Cool thanks :)

Comment: I love this answer, such an elegant and reusable correlation dataframe

Answer (score 2):

This should match the output you're looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create fake correlation matrix
corr_matrix = np.random.random_sample((5, 5))


ii, jj = np.triu_indices(corr_matrix.shape[0], 1)

scores = []

for i, j in zip(ii, jj):
    scores.append((i,j,corr_matrix[i,j]))

df_out = pd.DataFrame(data=scores,columns=['feature name 1','feature name 2','corr_coef'])\
           .sort_values('corr_coef', ascending=False)\
           .reset_index(drop=True)

threshold = 0.1

df_out[df_out['corr_coef'] > threshold]

#  feature name 1 feature name 2    corr_coef
# 0     0              2            0.990691
# 1     2              4            0.990444
# 2     0              1            0.830640
# 3     1              2            0.623895
# 4     1              4            0.433258
# 5     3              4            0.404395
# 6     0              4            0.291564
# 7     2              3            0.276799
# 8     1              3            0.177519
```

And you can map the indices of the features (in columns `feature name 1` and `feature name 2` above) to the columns of your df_1 to get the actual feature names.

So your complete function would look like this:

```
def find_correlated_features(df, threshold, target_variable):

    df_1 = df.drop(target_variable)

    #corr_matrix has in index and columns names of variables
    corr_matrix = df_1.corr().abs().to_numpy()

    ii, jj = np.triu_indices(corr_matrix.shape[0], 1)

    scores = []

    for i, j in zip(ii, jj):
        scores.append((i,j,corr_matrix[i,j]))

    df_out = pd.DataFrame(data=scores,columns=['feature name 1','feature name 2','corr_coef'])\
               .sort_values('corr_coef', ascending=False)\
               .reset_index(drop=True)

    # This should go from the second column as the index loop that gave us
    # the scores and indices were from the upper triangle offset by 1
    feature_name_map = {i:c for i,c in enumerate(df_1.columns[1:])}

    df_out['feature name 1'] = df_out['feature name 1'].map(feature_name_map)
    df_out['feature name 2'] = df_out['feature name 2'].map(feature_name_map)

    return df_out[df_out['corr_coef'] > threshold]
```

Comment: Thank you, I am closer to the solution thanks to your suggestions. In this solution I get the error:

"" "or i, j in zip (ii, jj):
---> 13 scores.append ((i, j, scores [i, j]))
      14
      15 df_out = pd.DataFrame (data = scores, columns = ['feature name 1', 'feature name 2', 'corr_coef']) \

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple "" "but hope to solve it. Thanks a lot, best regards!

Comment: Ah I just saw that I changed the corr matrix name to `corr_matrix` from something else and forgot to update it, and also missed an indent in the for loop! - I've fixed that now :) That should solve your error too?

Comment: Now I have key error (0,1) for this line :  scores.append((i,j,corr_matrix[i,j])) hmm

Comment: Ah I think I know what's happening. I've thought that the corr_matrix was a matrix, but I guess it's a dataframe? You can get it to a numpy matrix by doing `to_numpy()`

Comment: corr_matrix.shape 102, 102

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225223/discussion-between-user6386471-and-aly).